# Apache NiFi ConvertExcelToCSV processor "failed to read zip entry source" error is generated on a proper .xlsx file

Tags: java, excel, csv, zip, apache-nifi

I'm trying to process a large (1.3 GB) .xlsx file into .csv with ConvertExcelToCSV processor. The file is a proper .xlsx format, it has no groupings within the file. Error "failed to read zip entry source" is generated. I tried to significantly decrease the number of rows in the file and save as a copy and it worked fine, it was processed by ConvertExcelToCSV, so it seems to me that the error is somehow related to the file size. What can be a possible reason for that error and how can it be avoided? Thanks in advance.
NiFi version is 1.6.0

Comment: Do you have capacity to try the same flow in a more up to date version of NiFi? 1.11.4 or 1.12.1? 1.6 is very old

Comment: @Sdairs tried with 1.12.1, same error with a more detailed description like "ZIP entry is too large or invalid". Please check my response for this post below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally with the community help the error reason was found. As Excel is actually a "zip package" of xml files (one per each sheet), those xml are much larger than xlsx. The xml in the given 1.3 GB is around 10 GB (87% compression ratio). NiFi POI engine can't handle files larger than 2 GB.
So the recommendation is to check your Excel's contents (can be done by renaming .xlsx to .zip and opening with an archive tool), if it's more than 2 GB - you can't proces it with NiFi.

Comment: Do you have a link for where you found information regarding a 2GB limit?

Comment: @Sdairs here is the link to POI IOUtils docs https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/IOUtils.html
you can check toByteArray methods descriptions, the description of "length" parameter is: "length - The maximum length to read, use Integer.MAX_VALUE to read the stream until EOF."
Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2147483647 bytes (2 GB). Testing different files sizes showed that this limitation actually exists now, including NiFi version 1.12.1.